# Changing button image with dynamic name

Tags: c#

How can I change button image if button text included in my `List<>`?

I have added my button names and texts in Dictionary. I also have list of my room names.
 I have 40 buttons on the form and each button has numbers on it. Each button represents a room and button text is room number. My list NameRoom is reserved rooms list. I am trying to change picture of buttons that has reservation. So I am not trying to change text, I am trying to change image of button. Thanks

```
foreach (int roomN in NameRoom)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(roomN))
    {
        string buttonName = dictionary[roomN];
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Name = buttonName;

        //ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
        //var urisource = new Uri(@"Resources\dolu.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        //myBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(urisource);
        //button.BackgroundImage = myBrush;
        button.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Merdivan));

        //button.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Resources\dolu.jpg");   
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you really trying to change the name, or are you trying to change the text that appears on the button?

Comment: Are you actually displaying this button anywhere? From your code I caa't see how you can tell if this works or not?

Comment: that code just creates a new button and gives it name and image properties

Comment: sorry I editted text but it looks like didnt work and my actual question is not displayed. I have 40 buttons on the form and each button has numbers on it. Each button represents a room and button text is room number. My list NameRoom is reserved rooms list. I am trying to change picture of buttons that has resevation. So I am not trying to change text, I am trying to change image of button. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinForms?  If yes, try something like:

```
        foreach (int roomN in NameRoom)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(roomN))
            {
                string buttonName = dictionary[roomN];
                Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find(buttonName, true);
                if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Button)
                {
                    Button button = (Button)matches[0];
                    button.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Merdivan));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Button name. You have to give context in which you use name. I believe you wanted to say text.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Text = "Something"
```

This will change the text that is displayed on the button. If you really are trying to change the name than please give us the reason for doing so and some context.

Cheers

Comment: sorry I editted text but it looks like didnt work and my actual question is not displayed. I have 40 buttons on the form and each button has numbers on it. Each button represents a room and button text is room number. My list NameRoom is reserved rooms list. I am trying to change picture of buttons that has resevation. So I am not trying to change text, I am trying to change image of button. Thanks –

Comment: you are creating new button every time...instead try to find your instance of the button and change it